# ValidationMessage not showing up when using more than one model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validationmessage

I have the form that uses 2 models so I include that this way:

```
@model Equipment.Models.PublicViewModel
```

where PublicViewModel is

```
namespace Equipment.Models
{
    public class PublicViewModel
    {
        public Device Devices { get; set; }
        public UserCredentials Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For example UserCredential class looks like:

```
namespace Equipment.Models
{
    public class UserCredentials
    {
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data.UserName, new { @class = " input-group-addon" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Data.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data.UserName)
        </div>

        ...

        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Devices.DeviceSerialNumber, new { @class = " input-group-addon" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Devices.DeviceSerialNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Devices.DeviceSerialNumber)
        </div>
        ...
}
```

In other form when I use only one model everything works.
Can anyone tell me why this isn't working for 2 models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748703/ivalidatableobject-in-mvc3-client-side-validation) its confirmed that you can't have client side validation on nested objects. Only property level validators can emit client-side validation.

So rather the using DataAnnotations you could use `FluentValidation.NET` as stated by @Darin on [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136631/asp-net-mvc3-conditional-validation-of-nested-model-for-editortemplate) link

Still other way you can choose is to have separete partial view for both the models and calling those views from single view and passing models as needed to these views.

Like this

```
<div class="input-group">
        @Html.Partial("ViewForModelData", Model.Data)
        </div>


        <div class="input-group">
         @Html.Partial("ViewForModelDevice", Model.Device)
        </div>
```

Then you can have separate Validation summary in both these views!